# python-pptx How to make legend show Series name rather than category name

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

The code below produces the following chart:
[image]

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import ChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Cm


# create presentation with 1 slide ------
prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])
x = ['one','two']

specs = {
    'height': Cm(7.82),
    'width': Cm(14.8),
    'left': Cm(2.53),
    'top': Cm(5.72)}

data = ChartData()
data.categories = x
data.add_series('Series1', [5,6])
data.add_series('Series2', [4,5])

frame = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, specs['left'],
                               specs['top'], specs['width'],
                               specs['height'], data)
chart = frame.chart


chart.has_legend = True

prs.save('chart-01.pptx')
```

However, if I comment out this line `data.add_series('Series2', [4,5])` and only create one series then I get this image:
[image]

Notice the legend has changed from referring to the series to referring to the categories.

What I would like is for the legend to continue showing the series name rather than the category name. So I'd like, in the second chart for both one and two to be the same colour and the legend showing Series1. I have tried all kinds of different configurations of series and categories all unsuccessful. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the automatic behavior of PowerPoint. I think the idea is that for a single-variable chart, there would usually be no need for a legend as each color appears exactly once and is adjacent to its category name (and so is "self-legending", so to speak). In this case, one might typically suppress the legend and rely simply on the category-axis tick-labels.

The other option is to turn off "different-color-for-each-category", which will cause the series name to appear in the legend. This is controlled by the `plot.vary_by_categories` property:

```
chart.plots[0].vary_by_categories = False
```

Comment: Thanks @scanny that worked. Thanks so much for all these answers!